# today is the day when I will go to the movie with my boyfriend

Tags: expressions

"Today is the day when I will go to the movie with my boyfriend."

Is this phrase awkward somehow? Does "when" sound redundant?

Comment: Today is the day I go to the movie....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on context, it needn't sound awkward or redundant.

If the speaker were simply announcing a more-or-less spur-of-the-moment intention, then, as per [Nic's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/475966/102510), some variant like "*I will go to the movie with my boyfriend today.*" would be more natural.

However, if it were an event the speaker had been hoping to do for a while, and today is the day when it has become possible to do so, then this wording would be natural. If previous attempts had been thwarted for various reasons, you could even have "*Today is the day when I will **finally** go to the movie with my boyfriend.*".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds awkward to me and 'when' is not necessary, why not just write  ' I'm going to the movies today with my boyfriend' 
Unless you are making a pronouncement about today, for example ' Today is the first day of my new life'.